# Aligning images with captions side by side

Tags: html, css

So I've spent the last hour or so trying to figure out how to put captioned images next to each other. Most solutions/questions other people have don't work when I try to add text below it using figcaption or something of that sort.

I want the text to be underneath the images and move with the images but for some reason it moves the other image to another layer when I add text. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

(This is only a small portion of it because there's a lot of other stuff not related to this issue in that style)

```css
.gunimage {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#images {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img class="gunimage" border="0" alt="idk" src="gg.png" /></a>
  <p>this is text</p>
  <img class="gunimage" border="0" alt="idk" src="gg2.png" /></a>
  <p>this is also text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap your image and p inside another div to always keep them together. Building it this way creates unnecessary complexity and will create a lot of headache with responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses HTML 5 [`figure` and `figcaption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) elements, and CSS 3 [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
#images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

figure {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
        <figcaption>this is text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
        <figcaption>this is also text</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

NOTE: Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using floats

```css
.gunimage {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
}
.half {
  width:50%;
  float: left;
}
#images {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <div class="half">
    <img class="gunimage" border="0" alt="idk" src="gg.png">
    <p>this is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    <img class="gunimage" border="0" alt="idk" src="gg2.png">
    <p>this is also text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```